# One-to-one matching to labels for text classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am using `scikit-learn` for a text classification problem and I would like to know if there is a machine learning technique that uses a one-to-one, mutually exclusive mapping for labeling.

For example, say I want to label three documents based on what city they represent. My label choices are New York, Detroit and Los Angeles. My documents are "The Big Apple," "The Big City," and "City of Angels." Let's say just for this example that "City of Angels" most closely maps to Los Angeles, while both "The Big Apple" and "The Big City" should map most closely to New York. However, I want one to map to New York ("The Big Apple" because let's say that has a better fit) and one to map to Detroit because New York has already been used, and Detroit is the only choice that's left and it still fits in some sense.

I want to tell the predictor that if it has used one label, it cannot use it again, so it needs to make the best guess for that label since it can only be used once.

Does `scikit-learn` or another library have a feature for handling this one-to-one (and only one) text classification like I would like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this kind of functionality, I'd suggest you do the following:

I'd assume that in your text classification algorithm, you obtain a probability score for each document for every label.

e.g.:

```
  Documents  "The Big Apple"  "The Big City"  "City of Angels"

  Label     

  "New York"       0.45           0.45            0.1

  "Detroit"        0.4            0.5             0.1                

  "Los Angeles"    0.15           0.05            0.8
```

You might now be able to see where I am heading towards with this.

Use the argmax function (returns the label with the maximum probability for each document).

In this case, the argmax function would return the label "New York" for the documents "The Big Apple" and the "The Big City", the label "The Big City" for the document "Detroit" and the label "Los Angeles" for the document "City of Angels".

Since, in this case there is a conflict (I'd rather not call it conflict) in assigning a label "New York" for a document (since you require a one to one mapping), I'd say you go to the next label. The label "The Big City" can be clearly assigned to the document "Detroit" as it has the maximum probability (matching), and then you remove the label "Detroit" from the set of possible labels (remaining labels -> "New York" and "Los Angeles"). You then move on to the next label "Los Angeles" and the argmax function tells you that the document "City of Angels" has the highest probability (maximum matching) of having the label "Los Angeles". You then remove the label "Lost Angeles" from the remaining labels. At this point, remaining labels -> "New York". You then go to the next label "New York" and see that the only document it can be assigned to is "The Big Apple" and you have a one-to-one mapping between the documents and the labels.

I have done this before in two ways, breaking a tie by assigning a label to a document randomly, or by breaking the tie by calculating the probability for the next label. This technique is also used in a decision tree algorithm to find the most suitable attribute at a given level in the tree. It is called as the entropy or the information gain of that attribute. This implementation is a simpler version of the information gain from the ID3 decision tree algorithm.

More about the ID3 decision tree algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm).